# How do I test whether a newly created user can communicate with a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, django

My settings:

- Ubuntu 9.10
- PostgreSQL 8.4.2

I created a new user(jdoe) under my local PostgreSQL with the following command in the psql shell:

```
CREATE USER jdoe WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

I also have created a new database called `mydb`. My goal is to give user `jdoe` full access to database `mydb`.  I did a few things through the GUI pgAdmin III and after running `\l` in the psql shell, I get the following output:

```
                                    List of databases
Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------
mydb     | jdoe     | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 | =CTc/mydb
                                                           : hmart=CTc/mydb
postgres | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 |
```

Showing my list of users(`\du`), I get:

```
            List of roles
 Role name | Attributes  | Member of 
-----------+-------------+-----------
 jdoe      |             | {}
 postgres  | Superuser   | {}
           : Create role   
           : Create DB
```

I can't really tell from the above if my goal has been achieved, but is there a way to test if the user `jdoe` can communicate with the database `mydb`?  I'm testing it though Django's settings:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2'           
DATABASE_NAME = 'mydb'      
DATABASE_USER = 'jdoe'       
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'password'        
DATABASE_HOST = ''         
DATABASE_PORT = ''
```

but I'm getting the following error after a `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "jdoe"
```

I did all the above on Win XP with the latest PostgreSQL installer and everything work flawlessly with Django. I'm not sure what I'm missing under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have set it up in pg_hba.conf so that local socket connections must use ident authorization, while tcp connections to localhost are trusted. Read the documentation on pg_hba.conf for your version, eg 8.4 is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/client-authentication.html), and you can configure it correctly for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, setting `DATABASE_HOST` to `localhost` fix the issue:

```
# settings.py
DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost'
```

Comment: See above re pg_hba and tcp sockets vs unix domain sockets.

Comment: For some very strange reason this solved the problem for me